# Can I ask hardware specific questions here?

Tags: support

I'd like to ask why we need cpu modes, and also if being in one cpu mode applies to the entire IC or the cores. (not sure if this behaviour is ISA related. But if so, then in context of the x86 architecture)

By hardware questions I mean things that are really high tech, not like what voltage indicates a 1 or 0 inside a computer. But things that are above the instruction set border. Considering that the computer architecture is something that applies to all operating systems, so it wouldn't be a unix related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) seems to be an appropriate place for such questions;
see, for example,

- [Why so many modes are in CPU?](https://superuser.com/q/634733/150988)
- [Protected mode and Real mode](https://superuser.com/q/163971/150988)
- [Kernel and User mode distinguishing](https://superuser.com/q/167746/150988)

and [about 800 others](https://superuser.com/search?q=cpu+mode+is%3Aq).

Comment: Wow! Thanks didn't know you could search like this, I always used google^^ Well, I guess :a gives answers? Is there like a list somewhere about the search features? I am kinda new to the network and Don't know anything, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Once you've gotten into a [search](http://superuser.com/search), click on "Advanced Search Tips".  Or see [the Help Center](http://superuser.com/help/searching), or browse [meta questions about the search capability](//meta.superuser.com/tags/search/hot).

Answer (score 3):

> it wouldn't be a unix related question.

This seems an odd place to ask it then. Maybe [Super User](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: I agree on this, your right. Just wanted to clarify this.
It's just.. I have the feeling that on superuser are a lot of people asking everything, things that are even idk, not technical at all. Just take a look at this masterpiece. Second question on the active page.http://superuser.com/questions/1126747/csgo-frame-drops

I have the feeling that many experts stopped checking/using the site, (not considering myself an expert just a kid, who wants to know how the world works) duo to such posts that are literally flooding the frontpage.